# Camel-JsonPath blueprint

Tags: json, substring, blueprint

I have this Json:

```
{"request": {"cc": "000120000111SS000222M" }}
```

and this blueprint:

```
<route id="SGPIF-bonifico-dynamic-jetty">
      <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:9100/ifom/esterno/bonifico/dynamic?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
         <choice>
          <when>
          <jsonpath suppressExceptions="true">request.cc=~'0000111'</jsonpath>
          <log message="Json choice equals "/>
           <log message="SGPIF-bonifico-dynamic-jetty header: ${headers}"/>
           <to uri="log:SGPIF-bonifico-dynamic-jetty" />
           <wireTap uri="direct:requestEvent"/>
           <to uri="jetty:http://127.0.0.1:8080/om/esterno/bonifico/dynamic?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
           <log message="SGPIF-bonifico-dynamic-jetty-done header: ${headers}"/>
           <wireTap uri="direct:responseEvent"/>
           <to uri="log:SGPIF-bonifico-dynamic-jetty-done" />
         </when>
          <otherwise>
           <log message="Else choice"/>
           <log message="SGPIF-bonifico-dynamic-jetty header: ${headers}"/>
           <to uri="log:SGPIF-bonifico-dynamic-jetty" />
           <wireTap uri="direct:requestEvent"/>
           <to uri="jetty:http://127.0.0.1:8080/ifom/esterno/bonifico/dynamic?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
           <log message="SGPIF-bonifico-dynamic-jetty-done header: ${headers}"/>
           <wireTap uri="direct:responseEvent"/>
           <to uri="log:SGPIF-bonifico-dynamic-jetty-done" />
          </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </route>
```

In this case I'm filtering if this value 0000111 exists in json. Can I filter by position? I would like to do a substring on this 000120000111SS000222M.
Is there any way to do this?

Ok it work's fine with contains.But i need something like this:

```
setHeader headerName="JsonValue">
          <jsonpath>$.request.cc</jsonpath>
         </setHeader>
         <bean ref="parser" method="doSomething"/>
         <choice>
          <when>
          <simple>${header.JsonValue} == '0000111'</simple>
```

And trying to do something like this:

```
    public void doSomething(@Header("JsonValue") String jsonValue, @Body String body) {
    jsonValue += jsonValue.substring(5,12);

}
```

Comment: you can ommit setHeader part and write the following method
public void doSomething(@JsonPath("$.request.cc") String jsonValue, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) { 
  headers.put("JsonValue", jsonValue.substring(5,12));
}

Comment: Work's, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you put the value first in a header and then evaluate the headers value with simple language? see below

```
<setHeader headerName="CamelRequestCc">
  <jsonpath>$.request.cc</jsonpath>
</setHeader>

<choice>
  <when>
  <simple>${header.CamelRequestCc} contains '0000111'</simple>
    <log message="Json choice equals "/>
    ...
```